# How to display Google column chart x-axis label vertically?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using `Google chart` library to display column bar chart. My problem is some characters of x-axis label  are hidden , only some characters are shown , how can i show all characters?

My current column chart where some characters of x-axis labels are hidden.
[image]

I want to display like below picture, is it possible

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you can try.

1) `textPosition: 'in'`
you can print the axis labels inside the column but I don't think it will work with slanted text.
(see first example)

2) `chartArea`
you can adjust the size of the chart area to allow room for the labels.
(see second example -- added background color to highlight)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnnotations);

function drawAnnotations() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Company');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Score');

  data.addRows([
    ['Company A', .80],
    ['Company B', .80],
    ['Company C', .74],
    ['Company D', .74],
  ]);

  var options = {
    bar: {
      groupWidth: 100
    },
    hAxis: {
      textPosition: 'in'
    }
  };

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
  chart1.draw(data, options);


  var options = {
    bar: {
      groupWidth: 100
    },
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'cyan',
      height: 300,
      left: 32,
      top: 40,
      width: 434
    },
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true
    }
  };

  var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
  chart2.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
```

Comment: i wanted xaxis label be placed exact same as in image 2 but it seems impossible to achieve that . i will accept your answer as allternatives you suggested may be helpful for other

Comment: yes, only other way would be to modify the SVG once the chart's ready event has fired, or try to overlay your own labels -- neither good options